# How to create a dynamic line graph like Google Finance has?

Tags: jquery, charts, linegraph

I'm looking to create a dynamic zoomable line graph for a web page I'm doing.

I was told to "[make it like Google's one](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3aSPWRA)" (though by a sales guy who in turn is parroting the client, so he's aiming high. They'll all come right back down to earth once I tell him how much it'll cost!)

Can somebody recommend where to start with this? Are there any available jQuery plugins out there? Or other means of producing something similar?

Comment: Google will let you use theirs: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try google charting APIs like Wyatt noted, however, do keep in mind that google pulls data to its severs, and if your client has any privacy hassles, maybe thats not the solution to go for.

I would recommend these -
jqPlot - Good looks, MIT / GPL licence, interactive, http://www.jqplot.com/

flot - Good looks, Open source, interactive, http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Highcharts - Multiple licenses (might have to pay) http://www.highcharts.com/

Lots of other options, but these are all javascript based :)

Comment: Thanks for flot. Please advice MIT Licence is free of charge in commercial?

Comment: @Johnny_D Yeah, you can use [MIT licence](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html) for commercial stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [same toys google is using](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) for starters.

Answer (score 3):

Humble Software's [envision.js](http://www.humblesoftware.com/envision) also looks promising if you need to display time-series or stock charts.

http://www.humblesoftware.com/envision

finance/stock chart demo:
http://www.humblesoftware.com/envision/demos/finance

Comment: I would like to add that envision.js is free with MIT license.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest dygraphs. This one was developed intending to replicate google charts. It also has the range selector just like the google charts.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Amcharts' Stockchart](http://www.amcharts.com/stock/), <s>however it's a Flash based chart.  But</s> it's very solid, easy to implement and it works well with large datasets.

Their [regular Linechart product](http://www.amcharts.com/line/) is much cheaper and also has a pretty intuitive but less attractive zoom-scroll facility,.

EDIT: as pointed out by user mg1075, amcharts is now available as a Javascript chart.

Comment: amcharts is comprehensive and supports many chart types. However, for the stockchart, I found the chart content doesn't immediately update when I am dragging the mouse to change the display period. It only updates after I release the mouse. This function is present in most other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience I hope this is better  http://www.jqplot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've used and like the [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) library. easy to use and easy to get started. plus its based on jQuery.